# how to apply condition on RouteOnAtrribute for filter json data in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, minify

in nifi 
i have used invoked http processor that get data from web app.. i want to apply the condition on json data file ...i means when the resource="abc" the alarm get filter and goes to one processor and other alarm will go to another processor.....so my question is what are the processor is required..as of now i have used one http invoked that will provide all the alarm form my web app ..two putfile processor for storing alarm one for resource="abc" and one for other resource. and i have also used one Routonatrribute processor for condition..in RoutOnAttribute config i have decalred on dynamic property whic is ....the name of property is alarms.resource and the value is ${alarms.resource:equals('abc')}

Answer (score 1):

You can use QueryRecord to perform a SQL query on the flowfile such as `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE resource = 'abc'`. However if you will have multiple values for the `resource` field, you could use PartitionRecord. That will write out separate flowfiles, each one containing all rows that have the same value for `resource`. You'd still need to do routing at that point however.

Answer (score 0):

@AnnapurnaGautam

You need to get the resource into an attribute first (EvaluteJsonPath) and then use that attribute for RouteOnAttribute.  You cannot use the same coding EvaluateJsonPath in RouteOnAttribute.   For Example in EvaluateJsonPath:

```
checkResource = $.alarms.resource
```

Then code off that attribute in RouteOnAttribute:

```
 ${checkResource:equals('abc')}
```